# Keeping specific directories when zipping files, using SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, sevenzipsharp

In my Application im using the SevenZipSharp library and I want to compress an Array of Files.
Each of my Files is in the same Directory, for example:

- abc/xyz/file1.txt
- abc/xyz/file2.txt

When I call the Method `CompressFiles`, it cuts my Directory from the Compression while I want to keep the "xyz" Path of my Files. Is there a way to achieve this? Or do I have to use the CompressDirectory Method for this?

Example:

```
var myCompressor = new SevenZipCompressor
{
    ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.SevenZip,
    CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Lzma2,
    PreserveDirectoryRoot = true,
    DirectoryStructure = true,
    IncludeEmptyDirectories = true
};
string[] files = new string[2] { "abc/xyz/file1.txt", "abc/xyz/file2.txt" }
myCompressor.CompressFiles("somePath", files);
```

Result:

> - Archive
>
>   - file1.txt
>   - file2.txt

What I want:

> - Archive
>
>   - xyz
>
>     - file1.txt
>     - file2.txt

Comment: example here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/cupofdev/archive/2014/10/15/compress-files-and-folders-using-sevenzipsharp-and-7-zip-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the Link, but as I stated in my Question. I know about the CompressDirectory Call. My Question is, if you can achive this with the CompressFiles Method.